# Capture and play MJPEG - Network Video stream over UDP with OpenCV and ffmpeg

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, networkstream

I'm trying to receive and display a udp live mjpeg - network video stream from a network cam. 
I can play the video stream by starting VLC with the Argument `--demux=mjpeg` and then typing `udp://@:1234` in the network stream field. Or with gstreamer by the console line: `gst-launch -v udpsrc port=1234 ! jpegdec ! autovideosink`. My Cam has the IP Address `192.168.1.2` and it sends the stream to the address `192.168.1.1:1234`.

I've tried to capture the stream with OpenCV with:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap;
cap.open("udp://@192.168.1.1:1234");
```

I tried also:

```
cap.open("udp://@:1234")

cap.open("udp://@localhost:1234")

cap.open("udp://192.168.1.1:1234")

cap.open("udp://192.168.1.1:1234/")
```

But the function hangs until I press `ctrl+C`. I have the same problem when I use ffmpeg with: `ffmpeg -i udp://@192.168.1.1:1234 -vcodec mjpeg`

What did I do wrong? When i installed ffmpeg i couldn't install the dependency `libsdl1.2-dev`. Is that the problem?

If so, there is any way to read the udp-frames from the socket and then decode the JPEG pictures and display it with OpenCV?

I have the OS Ubuntu linaro oneiric 11.10 with the kernel 3.0.35 from Freescale

Comment: Have you tried "rtp://" or using .sdp files to describe the video stream?

Comment: Hello, yeah i have tried "rtp://" without success. to receive the stream with ffmpeg i have tried with ffmpeg -i udp://192.168.1.1:1234 -f mpegts -vcodec mjpeg.  sorry i dont know about using .sdp files

Answer (score 0):

thanks any way. i have fixed this problem by installing a newr version of ffmpeg and using the C-Api of ffmpeg